# [Python]what's wrong with my recursions?

Tags: python

I want to performe

```
  [√(1/2+1/2*√1/2)]  ---------(P1)
  [√(1/2+1/2*√(P1)]  ----------(P2)
  [√(1/2+1/2*√(P2)]  
  etc.
```

to find out the P(nth)term

I have this for now

```
from math import *

n=eval(input('fjeowijo'))
i=sqrt(1/2+1/2*(sqrt(1/2)))

def P(n):
  for i in range(n):        
      g=sqrt(1/2+1/2*i)
      i=sqrt(1/2+1/2*i)
      print(g)

P(n)
```

When I enter 1 for n, the result is 0.7071067811865476, which is only equal to the part " sqrt(1/2) ". Why?

Comment: In the for "i" in range, i is an iterator, when you set it to i=sqrt(..), it will be forgotten at the next iteration.

Comment: Please post your exact code for example you have print(x) but clearly x is not defined

Comment: @Arkantus but if i assign other word,like 'a', it shows [local variable 'a' referenced before assignment] error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to make it recursive do

```
def P(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return 0.5
    else:
        return sqrt(0.5*(1+sqrt(P(n-1))))
```

which works out as

```
>>> P(1)
0.9238795325112867
>>> P(2)
0.9902490907008235
>>> P(3)
0.9987774031336784
>>> P(4)
0.9998471169658009
```

As @JoshRomRock points out, python generally limits the maximum depth of the recursion (the default max depth is platform-dependent).
In case of CPython, the default limit is 1000.

In case you want to alter such limit do:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
```

Note: in this case, the precision offered by the floating point representation may well be the biggest hurdle to the calculation. Please see the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) for further info on what to expect using floats.

Second note: in case the `P` function is going to be used several times and/or in multiple points of the code of a program, as a library function, it would make sense to implement it using [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).
Please see [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) for a few examples in python.

Comment: You should be aware that Python call stack is limited to 1000 levels of recursion though.

Comment: @JoshRomRock thank you for the comment. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def P(n):
  i = 0
  g = sqrt(0.5+.5*sqrt(0.5)
  while(i < n):
    g = sqrt(0.5+0.5*g)
    print(g)
```

Could it be what you're looking for ?